# Filter Queryset with null condition

Tags: django, django-models

I want to filter records enabled today:

```
today = datetime.today().date()
dataset = Structure.objects.exclude(final_date__lt=today).filter(initial_date__lte=today)
```

The above code works fine with both initial and final day are filled.

How can I construct the filter considering that final_date can be null ?

Or Is there a better construction for this query?

Comment: Do you want to exclude records with a null date?

Comment: Yes. I want to filter records that aren't valid TODAY, considering initial and final dates fields the validity condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand this right, you would like to filter `final_date` for both value and null. Is it?

You could use Q objects for filtering.

```
from django.db.models import Q

dataset = Structure.objects.filter(Q(final_date__lt=today) | Q(final_date__isnull=True)).filter(initial_date__lte=today)
```